# wordpress child element negative margin-bottom doesn't apply

Tags: css, wordpress

I basically understand the CSS margin collapsing and overflowing child containers from parent containers using negative values for margins. When I try sample code in jsfiddle it works. But the issue is in my wordpress theme.

```
#header_margin {
    padding: 20px;
}

.header-container {
    margin-left: 34%;
}

#access {
    float: none;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 20px -20px -20px -20px;
}
```

The parent container is #header_margin and #access is the child. The left and right margin works fine. But the bottom margin doesn't work.

```
<div id="header_margin">
    <div class="header-container group">
        <hgroup id="header-title">
            <h1 id="site-title">
                <a href="http://localhost:8083/wp_test/" title="My Web Site" rel="home">My Web Site</a>
            </h1>
            <h2 id="site-description">Just another WordPress site</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <nav id="access" class="group" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="assistive-text section-heading">Main menu</h1>
            <div class="skip-link screen-reader-text">
            <div class="menu-main_menu-container">
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want navigation (#access) to cover the blue background (#header_margin). I think the issue is another CSS rule applied to one of the containers. But cannot find any other CSS rule which create padding or margins except for those two mentioned above.

Comment: Did you try to put important! in css ?

Comment: try using margin-bottom: -20px!important; this usually works when I have a hard time overriding the parent theme styles.

Comment: It didn't make any different to margin-bottom